# Locate a document (set) across site collection boundaries

Tags: site-collection, document, document-set, ecm

I have a scenario where I am investigating mechanisms to distribute storage of documents across multiple site collections.

This is primarily due to storage considerations, the best estimate is that we're looking at receiving roughly 900GB of documents per annum. Given that their client has a retention policy of at least 5 years and a desire to migrate their historical data into the SharePoint system I'm picking that we'll be hitting storage limit issues.

To counter these issues I'm considering partitioning the documents across site collections (with their own content DBs). I also need to ensure that the documents are logically grouped, usually by the contract number to which they relate.

The hitch comes in that I need to be able to route incoming documents to reside with other documents relating to the same contract. i.e if I receive a letter related to Contract xxyyzz I need to be able to route it to the correct site collection so that it can join the document set for that contract.

Is there any OOTB mechanism that I could leverage to find the target document set (where Contract Numbers Match) across multiple site collections?