# Document Set documents across multiple libraries and/or site collections

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-set

We are currently moving from Documentum to SharePoint 2013.

The question that came up how can we have a Document Set in SharePoint where documents are across multiple libraries and/or site collections?  ...like we are able to do in Documentum currently.

It looks as though SharePoint OOB Document set files are all under the same folder, so they cannot span libraries and/or site collections.

Looks like this could be the same requirement from another post:
[Locate a document (set) across site collection boundaries](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/23972/locate-a-document-set-across-site-collection-boundaries)

Thank you...and suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in that SP OOB Document Sets are just glorified folders, so no, there is no real way to technically have one Document Set that spans multiple libraries or site collections.

One idea off the top of my head though is that you could potentially make a custom Document Set that included a way to link to other Document Sets in different locations.  Then you could make multiple Document Sets with the same name and metadata in the different locations, and link them all together.

Answer (score 0):

A document set in SharePoint is a physical location - a box of stuff, if you will.  What you're asking for is a box of stuff that's all in different boxes - a logical impossibility.

So, you'll either have to move the documents into the same box, or you'll have to figure out how to recreate whatever feature(s) of document sets you require, without using document sets.

If you are migrating from a different platform into SharePoint, you have a golden opportunity to re-evaluate and fine-tune your information architecture - you'll have to live with it for years to come, so it behooves you to consider doing this.

The last thing you want to do is recreate Documentum in SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the link to document content type. It allows you to add links to your document set. This is a simple way of 'including' a document from elsewhere in the document set. Cheap and cheerful.